# Mockito - Is it possible to deep mock a void method call to do nothing?

Tags: testing, mocking, mockito

I wanted to know if it is possible to "deep mock" a void method call without breaking out the call chain, using Mockito.

This is an example for the original call I want to mock:

```
obj.getSomething().add(3);
```

where "add"'s return type is void.

I tried:

```
doNothing().when(obj).getSomething().add(3)
```

and:

```
doNothing().when(obj.getSomething()).add(3) //wont work since "when" expects a mock.
```

I also failed using Mockito.when(...) since it does not work with void methods.

I do not want to break the call up since it will be very cumbersome for fluent API calls that are much longer.

Is there an official solution / workaround for this scenario?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If the value returned by `getSomething` is not a mock, it won't work.
Return value of `getSomething` should be a mock and it will allow to assign mock behavior for that value.

```
Something someMock = mock(Something.class);
when(obj.getSomething()).thenReturn(someMock);
doNothing().when(someMock).add(3);
```

Comment: Hi :) thank you for your answer.
This I know as I stated in my question...
Wanted to know how can I do it without breaking up every link in the fluent call into a separate mock manually.

Comment: Unfortunately, even if you use `Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS`, I am not aware of a solution for `void` method. It can work great only for non-void methods.